# Finding part with simple html dom parser by two or more attributes per one element

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I would like to say, that I know, that many think, that Simple HTML DOM parser is a really bad choice for HTML parser. Still I need to use it at the moment.

I read some articles where it was described how to search by two or more attributes per one element.
They proposed something like that and one possibility with array filtering

```
foreach ( tag[attr1=value] as tag1 )
{
   foreach ( tag[attr2=value] as tag2 )
   {
      // print tag2[attr1=value,attr2=value]
   }
}
```

My question is about native posibility for finding part by two attributes. I didn't find it in the manual, but not everything is always in the manual.

Does anyone know is there such way or similar `tag2[attr1=value,attr2=value]` or `tag2[attr1=value attr2=value]` or etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see there is no way to do that at the moment. It should be edited by author of this script or by some other developer/s willing to continue the development of this project. Don't know does the license allow it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Never used Simple HTML DOM parser before. But its homepage says it works in jQuery way, so try `tag[attr1=value][attr2=value]` ([jQuery: Multiple Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/))

Comment: Tried this one. Nope. If I did everything correctly then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$doc      = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML( $html );
$xpath    = new DOMXpath( $doc );
$elements = $xpath->query( "//*/div[@class='name'][@id='someId']" );  

if ( $elements->length > 0 )
{
    foreach ( $elements as $index => $node )
    {
        //get node detail here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is a nice example of DOMDOcument functionality, but as the topic says I need specifically Simple HTML DOM parser. If it's not possible 100%, then I need someone to say it with 100% percent knowladge, that it is so.

Comment: you can not pars it 100% percent. It depends on HTML type I mean it show differences HTML to HTML. Also I did a mistak in example see check this  $xpath->query( "//*/div[@class='name'][@id='someId'][class='SomeClassName']"

Comment: And still you're talking about DOMDocument. This question is distinctly about **Simple HTML DOM parser** -> http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

probably after eight years they have came up with an updated version.

To use simple HTML DOM parser with more than one attribute,

```
foreach($dom->find('tag[attr1][attr2]') as $stuff){
    echo $stuff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell having looked through the simple_html_dom, there is no way other than a nested foreach loop to achieve the functionality you are looking for. There is no inbuilt support for `tag[attr=val][attr2=val]`

Additionally each selector acts simply to add to the returned nodes, never to take away from it so something like `tag.class[attr=val] or tag#id[attr=val]` which I tried as a work around which would have mimicked some similar functionality.

As well, I tried `$html->find("div[attr=val]")->find("div[attr2=val2]")` but this also failed as Simple HTML DOM returns an array of nodes rather than a new tree object making chaining impossible.

The best way to go is the way you've posted in your question.