# Simple-HTML-DOM: looking for a hasClass() method (or list of classes)?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have a list of `div`s with different classes. Let's say:

```
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="a b">A&B</div>
<div class="a">A</div>
```

I get these `div`s by `$res = $DOM->find('div.a')`
How can I determine, if a div also has the other class `b`?

Like `if ($res->hasClass('b')) { /*do ...*/ }`

I also noticed there are the methods `hasAttribute()` and `getAttribute()`, but they don't quite help me as I need to check for a class, which is an attribute itself.

Note: I don't want to select directly via class `b`.

Reference: https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual_api.htm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604411/finding-part-with-simple-html-dom-parser-by-two-or-more-attributes-per-one-eleme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve HTML element attributes using `getAttribute()` method, and `class` is one of those attributes. The method will return the string value of the attribute, so you need to check for other classes manually. Of course, you can easily extend `simple_html_dom` class and add a `hasClass` method:

```php
$src =<<<src
<div class="a">A</div>                                                                                                                                                   
<div class="a b">A&B</div>
<div class="a">A</div>
src;

$html = str_get_html($src);

foreach($html->find('.a') as $a) 
{
    // put all element classes in an array
    $classes = explode(' ', $a->getAttribute('class'));
    print $a . " has following css classes: ";
    print_r($classes);
}
```